# Cannot Display paragraph preview in pop-up window

Tags: jquery, text, reference, popup, hover

I have a problem displaying text from a

tag to a pop-up, I am experiencing reference errors, I can refer to the p tag until I show the p tag using my .click function, I just need help taking the displayed p tag after the click function and outputting it to my hover pop-up function here is my code.

```
    $('.Article h1 a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this.parentNode).next('p').fadeToggle(1000);
     $(this.parentNode).next('p').hover(function() { 
                         var paragraph  = $(this).next('p').text();
            $('#pop-up').find('h3').append(paragraph);
            $('#pop-up').show();
                }, function() {
        $('#pop-up').hide();
     });
  });
```

Here is the HTML Code:

```
    <div id="content">
    <div class="column">
    <div class="Article">
    <img src="images/SteveJobs.png" alt="Steve Jobs" Title="SteveJobs" />
    <h1><a href="#"> Computers changed Forever</a></h1>
    <p> The Brilliant Mind of Steve Jobs. </p>
     <a href="#" id="trigger">this link</a>

                <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                 <div id="pop-up">
                  <h3>Pop-up div Successfully Displayed</h3>

                 </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is  at `var paragraph  = $(this).next('p').text();`

i think you want `var paragraph  = $(this).text();`

inside `$(this.parentNode).next('p').hover(function() {`  `this` is already `paragraph` node

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7XJhS/)**

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/7XJhS/2/)**

```
  $('.Article h1 a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this.parentNode).next('p').fadeToggle(1000);
     $(this.parentNode).next('p').hover(function() { 
                         var paragraph  = $(this).text();
         if( !$('#pop-up').data("appended")){// THIS REMOVES multiple appending
            $('#pop-up').find('h3').append(paragraph);
             $('#pop-up').data("appended",true)
          }
            $('#pop-up').show();

                }, function() {
        $('#pop-up').hide();
     });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed the issue the only problem I have now is that everytime I hover over the paragraph it keeps appending the paragraph text to the pop-up, how can I write the code to just display it once when I hover over it?

Comment: I have one more issue when I hover over other p tags the first pop-up for the first article is always displayed is there anyway I could just refer to the p tag I'm hovering on and display the pop-up for the p tag it's associated with?

Answer (score 1):

See if [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/batandwa/UzEWT/) doesn't work for you. If this is what you want I can add some comments to justify the changes I made.

In brief:

1. I fixed the HTML. There were some tags not closed.
2. I moved the appending of the paragraph outside the hover so it's not repeated.
3. Used `find` instead of `next`. I must admit I couldn't get `next` to work and I have not figured out why.